# Why Autoclicker only works in a remote pc if is being monitored?

Tags: windows-10

I have an autoclicker running on a pc that stops working as soon as I disconnect from AnyDesk. The autoclicker is running on windows 10, and as soon as I close the session from AnyDesk it stops working, and works normally as soon as I connect again. I checked and the pc doesn't shutdown, sleeps or gets lock.

Comment: Why not use AHK to run the autoclicker instead?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem possible. The session needs to be active to simulate clicks as windows expects you to be logged onto windows to be able to click on things.

The only answer I found is [this](https://thebot.net/threads/windows-vps-how-to-simulate-mouse-and-keyboard-for-bots-and-auto-clickers.309822/) but I am not sure if this would work in your environment.

Comment: thanks, you gave me a light, so windows needs to detect an active display for it to work, and when disconnecting from anydesk there is none... so perhaps can be solved if I physically connect a display and mouse, although is not the desired solution or maybe going for a different operative system?

Comment: @Mart yes having a physical display connected would work fine (I don't think a mouse is needed) although you would need to physically be at the machine to start the clicks or change anything

Comment: @Mart what exactly are you trying to achieve? There are programs that can do automated actions on web pages and click buttons, etc. but it definitely depends on what you want to do.